# How to get ip address scan report from virus total api?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/ip-address/report'

params = {'apikey':'<API key>','ip':' 192.10.1.01'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(response.json())
```

If i run this code it is not  giving ip address scan report , it's giving something like this:

```
{'response_code': 0, 'verbose_msg': 'Missing IP address'}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please refrain from including any credentials.  Consider regenerating your apikey.

Comment: You might want to try deleting the space in front of the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

`https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/ip-address/report` URL is not valid. you have to use a valid URL to get a response from and make a request to that URL.
Try `response.text` instead `response.json()`